# Shortest Path in networkx with multiple 'key' nodes to visit between source and target

Tags: python, graph, networkx, shortest-path

I'am rather new to this.
I have no problem using the "path = nx.shortest_path(G,source=2001,target=406008)" etc. .
But in my case I need to visit mutiple nodes between the source and the target.

I found: [Shortest Path in networkx with 'key' nodes to visit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56460584/shortest-path-in-networkx-with-key-nodes-to-visit)

Different to this case I dont't need it for a directed Graph and I can't seem to make it fit for my case.

My network:

```
import networkx as nx #networkx 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt #interface for drawing
import pandas as pd
import copy

G = nx.Graph() #first try

pos = {
    2001: (1,13),#230 R Ende
    [...]  }

G.add_edges_from([
    (2000,2001,{'weight':2.6})
    [...]  ])
```

The nodes to visit inbetween the source and the target should/will be given in a "randome" order. The algorithm should find the shortest way to visit all of the nodes beetween the source and target nodes.

@vurmux arguably you'r the go to person. Having provided the answer in a rather close case.

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: Might help https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-best-algorithm-to-find-a-shortest-path-that-must-go-through-some-given-nodes

Answer (score 0):

If your 'key' nodes have an specific order, like you have to visit node 3 then 6 and then the destination, you can just find the shortest path from the source to 3 then from 3 to 6 and then from 6 to the target node.
Since You have to cross those nodes in that order, and you are calculating the shortest path, just combining the shortest path from each node to the next one gives the shortest path from the source to the destination that goes through your specified nodes.

If you don't have any specific order, that is a little bit harder, you can just execute the above algorithm for all different permutations of your key nodes and choose the shortest path, that is

1. Calculate source,3,6,destination
2. Calculate source,6,3,destination
3. Report the minimum

If you have too many 'key' nodes in between this get very hard very soon, since, there is `n!` permutations for a sequence of length `n`.

It can be made better, but not by much, since you are essentially asking for a solution of a Hamiltonian Path of another graph that is build from your graph(I will provide the construction further), and there is no non-exponential algorithm currently known for the Hamiltonian Path problem.

For construction the Hamiltonian Path problem, calculate all-pairs shortest path between your 'key' nodes that doesn't go across other 'key' nodes(just remove all other key nodes and run shortest path on that graph), create a complete graph with your 'key' nodes as nodes and weights equal to shortest path value between the pairs calculated earlier(the weight can be infinity if two nodes aren't connected to each other). Now Add source and destination to this graph and connect them with one edge to all the other nodes they are connected with in the original graph with shortest path weights. Now the answer to a Hamiltonian path in this new graph is equal to the answer of your question, the shortest path that goes through all key nodes in an order that the algorithm decides.

With this reduction, one can be certain that any solution to your problem that isn't exponential in the number of key nodes would also be a solution to the general Hamiltonian Path problem and since there is no polynomial algorithm is known for Hamiltonian Path, there is currently no sub-exponential algorithm(in terms of the number of key nodes) for your problem too.

Comment: Thank you @Fazel,

The first Version ist what I theorised myself.

The second won't be applicable beacouse there always will be nodes inbeetween the ones I need to get to. At least in the initial graph/network.

In my case the source and target are, to a good aproximation the same point. So TSL (traveling salesman problem) is applicable. Reading about it there are allready solutions/good aproximations for searches with thousand of targets (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem) (I know wikipedia ... but it's easyes to link)

Comment: I don't expect to ever need to visito anything close to a hundret target points.

That said I was hoping to to heavily use working/tested code just for productivity reasons, but have problems finding these mentioned solutions.

Anybody any pointers?

Thanks in advance